# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'providing_args'

Tags: python, django, signals, django-allauth

I am creating a Django website. I was recently adding permissions/search functionality using the allauth package. When I attempt to run the website through docker I receive the error message:

***File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth/account/signals.py", line 5, in 
user_logged_in = Signal(providing_args=["request", "user"])
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'providing_args'***

What is causing this error? I know usually a type error is caused by incorrect models.py files but I can't seem to access this file since it is a part of an external package.

**Urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    
    path('', include('climate.urls')),
    
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns = [
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ] + urlpatterns
```

Models.py

```
class Country(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key= True,
        db_index = True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable= False
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    population = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    emissions = models.FloatField(default=1)
    reason = models.CharField(default="", max_length=100)
    flags = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default="")
    page = models.URLField(max_length=300, default="")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Country, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'countries'
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['id'], name='id_index')
        ]
        permissions = {
            ("special_status", "Can read all countries")
        }

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def flag(self):
        return u'<img src="%s" />' % (self.flags.url)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('country_detail', args =[str(self.id)])

    flag.short_description = 'Flag'
```

My settings.py that handles allauth.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'climate:home'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT = 'climate:home'
ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER = True
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = False
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
```

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner

    self.run()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run

    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper

    fn(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 115, in inner_run

    autoreload.raise_last_exception()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception

    raise _exception[1]

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute

    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper

    fn(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup

    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate

    app_config.import_models()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 300, in import_models

    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module

    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth/account/models.py", line 12, in <module>

    from . import app_settings, signals

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth/account/signals.py", line 5, in <module>

    user_logged_in = Signal(providing_args=["request", "user"])

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'providing_args'
```

Comment: What's the full traceback of the error?

Comment: Just added it to the question.

Comment: what versions are you using of Django and allauth? Having just looked at various versions of documentation and source code, it seems that providing_args worked in Django 3.1 but doesn't in 3.2, and allauth v0.46.0 claims to be the one that provides Django 3.2 compatibility. So I'd guess you're using Django 3.2 (or later) but a version of allauth that's pre-0.46.0?

Comment: I am indeed using Django 4.0. and allauth 0.42.0 so do I need to downgrade Django or update allauth?

Comment: sorry, missed that you're replied to this (tagging me would have helped inform me!). Yes, you'll need to do one of those - perhaps even both (I'm not sure if the latest allauth supports Django 4).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Based on the comments, you're running Django 4.0 with an old version of AllAuth.  So you just need to update AllAuth and should be fine.

---

However, other people who **have upgraded AllAuth** and **are running Django 4.0** but *still* seeing this error may have custom AllAuth or other signals registered that include the `providing_args` argument.

In this case, you need to search your project for any signals (such as those often overridden in AllAuth: `user_logged_in` or `email_changed`) and remove the `providing_args=['request', 'user', 'signup']` or other variation from the `Signal` parenthesis.

See below for more information, and an example diff showing how you could move each `providing_args` argument to a commented line.

---

Django deprecated the ability to use the `providing_args` argument to `django.dispatch.Signal` in Django 3.1. See bullet in the [Misc section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/3.1/#id2) of the 3.1 release notes.

It was removed because this argument doesn't do anything other than act as documentation. If that seems strange, it is because it is strange. Arguments should indicate data getting passed. This is probably why it was deprecated.

Django 4.0 went ahead and removed this altogether, making any code that calls `Signal()` with the `providing_args` argument now trigger the TypeError you encountered:

`TypeError: Signal.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'providing_args'`

AllAuth removed the use of this argument in September of 2020. (See [original report](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/2678) on this issue here and the [referenced diff](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/commit/aee12c002ba64e5c6ccac1ef58cbbb1ab8663e96))

The person asking the question in this thread was running AllAuth `0.42.0` which does not include this change and is thus incompatible with Django 4.0.

As of today, the last version of Django AllAuth `0.42.0` *is* compatible with is Django 3.2.9.

Answer (score 8):

I solved the same problem by replacing

```
check_request_enabled = Signal(providing_args=["request"])
```

to

```
check_request_enabled = Signal("request")
```

and now its working perfectly.

Comment: This will work in case you want to test the demo in https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/demo.html

Answer (score 3):

This is for anyone who faces the same issue on `Django 4.0` and is not using `AllAuth`.

I ran into a similar issue. However, I was not using `AllAuth`.
The problem is that `Django 4.0` does not have any `providing_args` parameter, so the signal is declared this way.

```
from django.dispatch import Signal

model_delete_signal = Signal()
```

Now, you can send any arguments when sending the signal, which will be received in `kwargs` in the receiver.

For example, I sent the following `instance` argument while sending the signal in my custom delete function

```
model_delete_signal.send(sender='session_delete', instance=self)
```

and received it this way inside the receiver

```
@receiver(session_delete)
def delete_session(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
```

Note that, the solution is the same for any Django versions that don't have `providing_args` parameter in `Singal()`

Answer (score 2):

This is valid also for the ones not using `AllAuth`.

There are better explanations to the question but this is what worked for me...

According to Django

> The **purely documentational** providing_args argument for Signal is deprecated. If you rely on this argument as documentation, you can move the text to a code comment or docstring.

Just comment out the following code from signals.py file in your local project storage:

```
user_logged_in = Signal(providing_args=["request", "user"])

# Typically followed by `user_logged_in` (unless, e-mail verification kicks in)
user_signed_up = Signal(providing_args=["request", "user"])

password_set = Signal(providing_args=["request", "user"])
password_changed = Signal(providing_args=["request", "user"])
password_reset = Signal(providing_args=["request", "user"])

email_confirmed = Signal(providing_args=["request", "email_address"])
email_confirmation_sent = Signal(
    providing_args=["request", "confirmation", "signup"])

email_changed = Signal(
    providing_args=[
        "request", "user",
        "from_email_address", "to_email_address"])
email_added = Signal(providing_args=["request", "user", "email_address"])
email_removed = Signal(providing_args=["request", "user", "email_address"])
```

This means **one does not have to place the inputs of the removed `providing_args` argument anywhere, since their function was *purely documentational*.**

It is recommended though to move those inputs to a code comment or docstring.

You can find this in

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/allauth/account/signals.py
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't know why this happening but (it works on my machine) i solved the same problem by replacing

```
user_logged_in = Signal(providing_args=["request", "user"])
```

with

```
user_logged_in = Signal()
```

in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth/account/signals.py

Comment: See my answer for a complete explanation of why this works.

Comment: Thanks a lot sure , you did really great job explain it.

Answer (score 1):

From the [django documentation for django 3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/3.1/#id2):

> The **purely documentational** providing_args argument for Signal is deprecated. If you rely on this argument as documentation, you can move the text to a code comment or docstring.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Signal without argument in new version of Django 4. like this

```
from django.dispatch import Signal, receiver
notification=Signal()
@receiver(notification)
def show_notification(sender, **kwargs):
    print("sender,", sender)
    print("Kwargs", kwargs)
    print("Notification")
```

and after where you use this Signal write like this

```
notification.send(sender=None, request=request, user=['Sakib', 'Malik'])
```

Answer (score 1):

First check your `signals.py` file, where you use `Signal()` function

```
SignalName = Signal(providing_args=["request", "user"])
```

In `Signal()` function don't give `providing_args` as parameter, give arguments like

```
SignalName = Signal(["request", "user"])
```